# python - mark unit tests by different categories: unit, integration, "dangerous_integration"

Tags: python, unit-testing

Question is, is there a way mark unit tests by different categories: unit, integration, "dangerous_integration". Then from say "Team City" setup, auto skip "dangerous_integration"?

For tests which is marked "Dangerous" - they should not be run automatically. Those need run manually, preferably even on debugger with very close watch?

For python, here's an example where a class I have that can send live trades to crypto exchanges. I essentially shunt all test methods with a "return" as first line of test method to avoid situation where we send live trades out to the street unintentionally.

```
import unittest
class BinanaceConnectorTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        ... 

    def tearDown(self):
        ...

    def testSendRealOrders(self):
        return <-- I hardcode return here so nobody accidentally 
        ... actual implementation shunted by above return ...
```

Is it the proper way of doing this? I am using Visual Studio. I remember in C# with xunit, there's way you can mark unit tests by different **categories**.

I am thinking there isnt such thing as "dangerous_integration" tests - if you need such thing, separate those tests out to a manual python script and simply don't mark them as unit tests of any kind. That'd be safest.

Comment: Your tests should not be communicating with outside services, period. Use `unittest.mock` to replace the "dangerous" calls with something benign, or (better yet) design your code to allow an alternate communicator to be used in testing. (As an example, a function that takes a file name and tries to open it should take a file-like object instead. In product use, the desired file is opened first, then passed to the function. For testing, you pass a `StringIO` or `BytesIO` instance. You can do something similar with whatever library you use to connect to the crypto exchange.)

Comment: Here's really testing exchange integration, so actually cant mock anything. For things like getting market data, or trade history, fine can put under unit tests. But sending live order is too dangerous. On the flip side, if such test not automated, each time run manually, that's a lot of work.

Comment: `unittest` provides ways to write a custom test runner that gives you control over which tests are actually selected to run. At the very least, you can isolate your live tests to their own module(s), and have your test runner skip those modules.

Comment: There's also the `skip` decorator you can use to skip the live tests, but I wouldn't even risk putting them in the same module with other tests

Comment: yes thanks, safety first!

Comment: Do you connect via http? The `vcr` library may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The scenarios for selective test execution that you have presented (like dangerous_integration) should probably better be addressed in a different way, as was already discussed in the comments.  There are, however, situations where you want certain tests to be excluded in the normal case.  For example, you might have some long-running tests which you only want to execute occasionally.  Or, some tests produce outputs beyond simple 'passed' or 'failed' results that require thorough analysis, which you also only want to run at times.

One approach can be to group these tests into classes of their own and use this to include or exclude them from the respective runs.  Or, if it seems more appropriate to have these tests implemented together with other tests, you could use some naming convention that indicates to which category a test belongs.  You have the option to selectively run tests that are grouped or named in certain ways as is described in the Python unittest manual: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/unittest.html.  For example, the attribute `testNamePatterns` of `unittest.TestLoader` could be used for the selection of tests based on their names.